# How to annotate matrix using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices, annotations

so not really sure on how I can achieve this, I have tried to do it so far with tikznode and didn't get it to look like I wanted, granted not really sure of what I'm doing. This is the output I'm trying to get :

[image: desired output]

This is the basic code I'm using, without any annotation added to it :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathrsfs}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, decorations.pathreplacing,shapes,shapes.geometric,hobby,patterns,babel,matrix,calc}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Mat}{Mat}
\begin{document}
$L_{ij}(k) \rightarrow E_{ij}(k) =  \begin{pmatrix}
1 & & & \\
& 1 & & \\
k & & \ddots & \\
& & & 1
\end{pmatrix}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a variation on the answer of `user121799`.

Instead of using `tikzmark`, it's possible to use `nicematrix`. That package provides an environment `{pNiceMatrix}` similar to the classical environment `{pmatrix}` (of the package `amsmath`) but which creates PGF/Tikz nodes under the cells, rows and columns.

It's possible to use these nodes with Tikz in the same way done by `user121799` in his answer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

$L_{ij}(k) \rightarrow E_{ij}(k) =  
\begin{pNiceMatrix}
  1 & &        & \\
    & 1 &      & \\
  k & & \ddots & \\
    & &        & 1
\CodeAfter
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[<-] (2) to[out=45,in=180] ([xshift=2.5cm]1-1) 
           node[right,anchor=north west,align=left,yshift=\baselineskip]{some long text\\ and more text};
  \draw[<-,shorten <=3pt] (3-1.west) --++ (-0.4,0) node[left] {text};
  \draw[<-,shorten <=3pt] (3-1.south) --++ (0,-0.8) node[below] {more text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{pNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations because of the PGF/Tikz nodes.

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 13):

[The new version of `tikzmark`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark?lang=en) is soon part of the standard TeX distribution. It contains a command `\tikzmarknode`, which can be used as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathrsfs}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Mat}{Mat}
\begin{document}
$L_{ij}(k) \rightarrow E_{ij}(k) =  \begin{pmatrix}
\tikzmarknode{l1}{1} & & & \\
& \tikzmarknode{l2}{1} & & \\
\tikzmarknode{k}{k} & & \ddots & \\
& & & \tikzmarknode{l3}{1}
\end{pmatrix}$
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[<-] ($(l1.center)!0.5!(l2.center)$) to[out=45,in=180] 
($(l1)+(2.5cm,0)$) node[right,anchor=north west,align=left,yshift=\baselineskip]{some long text\\
and more text};
\draw[<-,shorten <=3pt] (k.west) --++ (-0.4,0) node[left] {text};
\draw[<-,shorten <=3pt] (k.south) --++ (0,-0.8) node[below] {more text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that you may have to update your TeX distribution to run this (in case you do not yet have the newest version of the `tikzmark` library).